# Customizing UINavigationBar and DRY rule

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a lot of code related to changing `UINavigationBar` elements. I have to use it in almost every one of my view controllers and every time I need to set a custom `UILabel` `titleLabel` with the title of a view.

What is the best way to use this code in many views and not repeat the same code? Should I create another class and then import it into my view controllers and use a method from that class to set title every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a subclass of `UIViewController` with all the 'common' stuff, and have all the specific view controllers inherit from that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the appearance settings globally by doing:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I took this code snippet from appdelegate of the open source cheddar app:

https://github.com/nothingmagical/cheddar-ios/blob/master/Classes/CDIAppDelegate.m

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is I need to set a custom `UILabel` on my `UINavigationBar` and set its value depending on a view.